# JSON extract array elements

Tags: java, json

Given the following JSON

```
{  
   "Users":[  
      {  
         "Username":"John",
         "Password":"Doe"
      },
      {  
         "Username":"Anna",
         "Password":"Smith"
      },
      {  
         "Username":"Peter",
         "Password":"Jones"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to extract an array list of `UserName` & `Password`

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray userArray = jobj.getJSONArray("Users"); // Now I got the Array of Users
```

I need to do something to extract all the user and password. What function is there for this? I am using the org JSON library

```
for (int i=0;i<userArray.length();i++)
{
    // something like that
    usernameList = userArray[i].getData("Username");
    passwordList = userArray[i].getData("Password");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
usernameList = userArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Username");
```

Answer (score 1):

to get a List of all userNames and Password you need to iterate through all the elements in the array and then add individual userNames and passwords to the lists.

Something Like this:

```
    List<String> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> passwordList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject user = userArray.getJSONObject(i);
            userList.add(user.getString("Username"));
            passwordList.add(user.getString("Password"));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```